# Is it possible to use (with PHP) prepared statements that have been previously declared in the mysql CLI?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

In the mysql CLI I have prepared a statement like this:

```
PREPARE registrarUser FROM 'INSERT INTO Users (Users_name,Email,pass) values (?,?,?)'
```

In my database the prepared statements have to be done this way,instead of using a php method like this::

```
$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Users (Users_name,Email,pass) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
```

So I can't use the prepared statement or bind arguments.

I have tried this query which mimics the required statements in mysql CLI

```
$query = sprintf('
SET @Users_name = "%s";
SET @Email= "%s";
SET @pass = "%s";
EXECUTE registrarUser USING @Users_name, @Email, @pass;',$Users_name,$Email,$pass);
```

But it returns the following syntax error:

```
Errormessage: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @Email= "eds@gmail.com"; SET @pass = "Thinkshap2"; EXECUTE registrar' at line 2
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to do it?
Thank you very much in advance;

Comment: Why exactly can't you use the statement you just prepared in PHP? There are methods such as `$stmt->bindParam()` and `$stmt->execute()`. Also your _workaround_ is open to SQL injection.

Comment: Yes, but that way I have to have prepared the sentence in php previously, right?

Comment: Yes, prepare, bind, execute... all in PHP. The library will generate the `PREPARE ...` and `EXECUTE ...` statements that are sent to MySQL.

Comment: Please share more details. The code you've shown can not result in the given error message, as you are not doing anything with that `$query` variable

Comment: @NicoHaase Why can't it? Of course it can. You can't execute multiple statements with `mysqli_query()`

Comment: @Dharman there's no occurence of `mysqli_query` in the given question

Comment: You can only use multiple statements in one query with [mysqli_multi_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php). If you don't use that, either by using `mysqli_query` or PDO, then you're going to receive that syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Prepared statements have the session scope. Whenever you open a new connection in PHP, you open a new MySQL session. You can use `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` in PHP, but both operations have to be done using the same session.

In other words, statements created with `PREPARE` do not persist on the database server. They only exist for the lifetime of the current session.

The reason why you are getting a syntax error in PHP is because you have concatenated multiple SQL statements together. You can't do that by default in PHP due to security considerations. Execute each one separately. For example, this works:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->query("PREPARE registrarUser FROM 'SELECT ?'");
$stmt = $mysqli->query("EXECUTE registrarUser USING 32");
```

**Warning**. Using `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` from PHP defeats the main purpose of prepared statements usage in PHP. The main advantage is that you can separate variables from SQL syntax. You can't do that with `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`. This is why both PDO and mysqli have prepared statements. Use `mysqli::prepare()` and `mysqli_stmt::execute()`

Comment: Okay, so there is a double bug in my problem. I suppose that creating a `procedure` is the most efficient, since it is compiled in mysql, isn't it? Thanks.

Comment: @FER31 Most efficient to do what? I wouldn't recommend stored procedures for anything. They are really annoying to use. Why can't you just use PHP prepared statements?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible.

From the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html)

> The scope of a prepared statement is the session within which it is created...
>
> - A prepared statement created in one session is not available to other sessions.